# What happened to the comments? They all disappeared

Tags: support, comments

I had [posted a question on a silly CSS issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41576846/odd-irregular-float-css-elements-in-the-browser)  I'm pretty sure there were four comments on the original question and at least two comments on the answer.  I made two or three of those comments.   The comments told a valuable story as to exactly why the issue was occurring (which the answer does not.. Its a broad brush 'how' answer remotely related to the issue, but not really, and not a 'why' answer...)  The comments specifically addressed element heights.

No way was there anything remotely offensive posted, yet all the comments have mysteriously disappeared.  Is there a way to tell what happened to the comments?

By removing those comments, the whole posting tells quite a misleading story.  The comments did tell EXACTLY what to fix in the CSS style sheet, and why that works that way, and that info is NOT in the answer proposed. Instead, ALL the comments on this question appear to be simply deleted.  What's up with that?   I'll try to recreate the comments (and answer the question myself) but that would have been so much easier had the comments not been removed.

Comment: I guess http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99812/who-has-the-power-to-delete-a-comment could help,

Comment: Don't recreate the comments. For this, and in future cases, if there's more information that clarifies the question, edit the question and add it. Even if someone asks you for specific information in a comment, it's usually better to provide the information by editing the question rather than giving it in a comment reply, especially if it's code.

Answer (score 11):

One party in the conversation self-deleted their comments and flagged the remaining comments as obsolete. Moderators then deleted those comments as they either replied to the deleted comments directly or were made in reference to them.

Comments are always ephemeral, temporary pieces of information. If there is something important in those comments, then consider moving that information into the question or answer.

Comment: I hear you, but that doesn't make sense.  I make a comment, and somebody else comments BELOW me... then they remove their comment.  How does my note all of a sudden become obsolete?  Bunk.  I cry foul.  Something is amiss here.  And what's worse is the posted answer really poorly addresses the issue.  So.. was the person who posted that mediocre answer the one who flagged ALL the comments on the page?

Comment: No, the answerer was not involved here, they never commented in the first place.

Comment: And you weren't the first to comment, not on the question. The commenter retracted their view, and the remaining conversation became obsolete. There is nothing nefarious going on here.

Comment: I got that.  I was the FIRST to comment on the submitted answer.  I told that submitter why I was not accepting the answer.  That comment was top of the list.  Why did that comment disappear?

Comment: Again, because it was marked obsolete, and we saw no reason not to honour it. The (deleted) reply read: *@zipzit The previous comment was incorrect and someone voted up which could be confusing to other people. At least that pointed you to the right direction, no worries.* Because they deleted the comments on the question, your comment was left without context. It was obsolete.

Comment: Martijn, thank you for your research on this.

Comment: I self-deleted a comment earlier and flagged a reply to it as obsolete, to my surprise it disappeared _literally within a second or two_ - in the time it took to refresh the page, or perhaps as a result of the flag dialog closing, I'm not sure which.  It made me wonder if there's anything automatic about this, but now seeing this Q&A I'm wondering if it really was just handled that quickly?

Comment: @JamesThorpe: you flagged something with a trigger word in it (*accept* in your most recent flag). Some keywords lower the flagging threshold (enough community flags can delete any comment without mod intervention).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah right, I didn't realise such things existed - do you know if there's any documentation for that sort of thing if I go looking?

Comment: @JamesThorpe: See [Who has the power to delete a comment?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/99812), the exact triggers are not public.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks!

Comment: @MartijnPieters *Comments are always ephemeral, temporary pieces of information.* [Except when they're not, of course](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341211/215552). :)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: that comment was mostly mis-flagged, and it has since been deleted.